# Press button, old input value saved and clone new input to save again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how do I do something like http://codepen.io/jacoblwe20/full/nbalL or http://stackedit.io. I want to implement it into my current project.

When I click the submit button, the old value I typed is saved to localstorage with key name 'save1', it clones the new input and saved with key name 'save2'.

Is that possible using jquery or javascript?

Comment: Could you revise your question or clarify here please? I wasn't sure if your saying that you have code that saves against 'save1' in local storage and a blank value into 'save2' or that you want to save a value into 'save1' and 'save2' on consecutive submits.

Comment: do you mean you want the old value (if it was submitted before) in 'save1' and the current value in 'save2'?